# Pandas - DataFrame object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
df(df.Sex=='male')
```

I get an error stating that the DataFrame object is not callable.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and need `[]` only:

```
df[df.Sex=='male']
```

Or:

```
df.query("Sex =='male'")
```